# jQuery-comments plugin not running

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-plugins

There a exist a brilliant comments plugin that I would like to implement on my site. It can be found here https://github.com/Viima/jquery-comments.

However I am having difficulty getting anything to appear when I try to implement it (first time using a plugin). Any suggestions would be great. Below is my code. (I would provide a JSFiddle however the external resources require links starting with "https.." and mine begin with "http...")

HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name=description content="">
        <meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://**MYURL**.net/jquery-comments.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://**MYURL**.net/jquery-comments.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="comments-container"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#comments-container').comments({
        getComments: function(success, error) {
            var commentsArray = [{
                id: 1,
                created: '2015-10-01',
                content: 'Lorem ipsum dolort sit amet',
                fullname: 'Simon Powell',
                upvote_count: 2,
                user_has_upvoted: false
            }];
            success(commentsArray);
        }
        });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following part of the code that you have typed has a few issues.

```
<script rel="text/javascript" href="http://**MYURL**.net/jquery-comments.js"></script>
```

You are using `rel="text/javascript"` and `href="http://**MYURL**.net/jquery-comments.js"` instead of `type="text/javascript"` and `src="http://**MYURL**.net/jquery-comments.js"`

Ultimately, you should replace the aforementioned block of code with the following one:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://**MYURL**.net/jquery-comments.js"></script>
```

**Script** tags are using **type** attribute to indicate the type of document that is called (which isn't really a good practice to use anymore according to latest Javascript standards). Also, in order to load, within the script tags, a Javascript file, you have to use **src** attribute instead of **href**.

Compare your code with the following one: https://github.com/Viima/jquery-comments#quick-start

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you. Also what other attributes are more appropriate to use other than 'type' with the new javascript standards?

Comment: I am glad it fixed your issue. HTML5 is clever enough to understand what kind of script is loaded when you point it to a specific source. That's why it's fine if you simply omit `type="text/javascript"`.

Comment: Ok great. Thanks again